# Using Google EmailSettings API to set multiple forward addresses through Filters

Tags: python-2.7, google-email-settings-api

If email forwarding enabled and email address set, then need to add additional forward address(es). Since gmail does not allow more than 1 forwardTo, want to use filters. So, for **all incoming mail**, want these to be **forwarded** to the currently set forward addresses and additional email addresses.  Currently using Service Account OAuth2 authentication. Am able to retrieve/set forwarding, but not sure how to set/append filter(s) & criteria as shown in table at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/.
Python service account auth code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039461/3692570

```
client.CreateFilter(username='username', to='emailaddress', forwardTo='emailaddress') <-- ??
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#creating_a_filter which has information on how to create filters and examples of it.

Comment: I'm currently running into this same thing. As far as I can tell, the GData Python client currently does not actually support setting forwards on filters. I'm working on a workaround right now to hopefully address that, and will issue a pull request to try and get this feature included upstream.